# How to access Tumblr API Photo Data Feed (i.e. all photos, entire archive)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, api, tumblr

I am currently developing a project in PHP that connects to Tumblr photo blogs via Tumblr API with my api-key to access posted photos in specified Tumblr photo blog.

I used the Tumblr API documentation to get started and have cross-referenced many web sites (including this one) and books, and have managed to "hack"/piece together a program that retrieves the Tumblr photos from specified blog.

I have successfully connected and retrieved photos by parsing the array with multiple foreach & if-else control-flow statements, and then placing the URLs retrieved of each photo in an array for later processing.

However, no matter which Tumblr blog I connect to and retrieve photos from, there are only 19 photos retrieved in the array of URLs for each Tumblr blog - and I would like to retrieve all of them.

I know that Tumblr loads a few images at a time, and then more pictures are loaded either by clicking "next/previous/older" and/or infinite scrolling down to load more images (especially in the archive).

Here is the example URL with api-key I use to connect to Tumblr:
[http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/EXAMPLEBLOG.tumblr.com/posts/photo?api_key=API-KEY-NUMBER"](http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/EXAMPLEBLOG.tumblr.com/posts/photo?api_key=API-KEY-NUMBER%22)

So my question(s) are:

1.) Is there way to access all the posts/photos with just one API call as per above?  (I have tried to EXAMPLEBLOG.tumblr.com/archive, but this retrieves nothing.)

2.) Is there any way to access the entire Tumblr photo archive?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

** UPDATE 27 / JULY / 2016 **

The following link works fine and gets 20 images from Tumblr blog photo posts:

```
api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/EXAMPLEBLOG.tumblr.com/posts/photos?api_key=XXXXX‌​XXXXXXXX
```

The following link **does not work** and makes the page barf and the photos to disappear:

```
api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/EXAMPLEBLOG.tumblr.com/posts/photos?limit=50?api_key=XXXXX‌​XXXXXXXX
```

The PHP print()/print_r()/var_dump() output I did (to help me program) indicates that the problem is here (so how would I solve this?  Do I need to do more back-end user-permission/user-token/OAuth-token/secret-token back-end PHP programming to access this possibility to get photo limit of 50 in Tumblr as per help advised by lharby(in comments) below?):

```
RAW JSON DATA = Array ( meta => Array ( [status] => 401 [msg] => Unauthorized ) [response] => Array ( ) 

ARRAY OF KEYS = Array ( [0] => meta [1] => response ) 

ARRAY OF VALUES = array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["status"]=> int(401) ["msg"]=> string(12) "Unauthorized" } [1]=> array(0) { } } 

TEST PHOTO EXTRACTION
HERE IS THE $Array0 INFO, KEY = 0 Array
HERE IS THE $ArrayResponse INFO, KEY = status401
HERE IS THE $ArrayResponse INFO, KEY = msgUnauthorized
```

Comment: You can call a maximum of 50 posts via the API in a single call. You can also use an offset, so for the next call retrieve 50 posts, starting at 51 etc. https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and help to get me in the right direction!  GOD bless you!  Unfortunately I am still a bit in the dark.

How do I make a single call in the API?  And what is an offset?  Can I do an offset and single API call in PHP?  Do I need to code more than what I have already coded with the simple URL api-key API call?  Is there any way I can just add more details to/before/after the api-key in the URL?  Or do I have to do more complex coding.  I can do the coding, but would need to know the direction where to start doing the coding and further research there.  Thank u!

Comment: I see offset as a parameter in the link you sent.  It looks like I may be able to do this in that simple URL with additional variables and parameters.  Thank you so much.  ...However, in the link you sent, I do not see a parameter how it is possible to set the number of posts to 50.  Where is it possible to do this?

Comment: I see a limit parameter in the link that you sent, but I see that it is 1-20 with 20 maximum.  Actually the 19 that I saw was the last number of the 0-19 array, so I count 20 photos retrieved via the above API call.  I would like to expand this even to 50.  I will test if I can make that limit 50 and see if 50 can be retrieved (but the Tumblr API says 20).

Comment: No, making ?limit=50 (right before the ?api-key = ...)didn't work.  In fact, it just made the other pictures disappear from the page.  So this just made my page "barf".  Is there more detailed underlying layer of Tumblr API where I can access the posts/photos with more PHP programming?

Comment: This works for me making an ajax call (I don't know so much about php) https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/slack-wise.tumblr.com/posts?limit=50 with your api key of course. If the offset did not work please check the console for any errors.

Comment: In terms of using the offset (certainly in javascript) you have to create a success function when the call receives the object from the API, when that success function runs you can then iterate over the same url but add the offset as a parameter. So each time you would increment your offset value by 50.

Comment: Even your link makes the page barf and the photos to disappear.  I don't know what is [JavaScript?] console, but the PHP output I did indicates that the problem is about permissions of my api-key when making this request (because connecting to the simple Public API of the web site with no additional parameters works fine.  But adding these parameters as per your link makes the response (as per code made in edit of original post here 27 / July / 2016) "Unauthorized".

Comment: I am trying this as per your link, but it does not work, and we should note that you are setting limit on the posts and not posts/photos:

api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/slack-wise.tumblr.com/posts/photos?limit=50?api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118404/discussion-between-lharby-and-jerusalem-programmer).

Comment: How do we continue this discussion in chat?

Comment: Follow the link that was automatically created in my comment. Or here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118404/discussion-between-lharby-and-jerusalem-programmer