# How do i load more images from a tumblr blog?

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, tumblr

I am trying to make a script that downloads x amount of images(recent, for example), from a use specified blog. I have tried to use `http://EXAMPLE-BLOG.tumblr.com/archive`, which in the browser has an "infinite scroll" function. I prefer to do this in python, and i have done quite a bit of web scraping before, but i dont understand what kind of a request i can send to get more images. It does not need to use html or the archive page, if you can send me to some kind of API that does this. I have googled for a while and also searched StackOverflow, but i have been unable to find what i want. ..../archive gives 50(or 51) posts, while the RSS feed only gives around 20 posts. Is the scrolling and loading of more pictures on the website server or client side? Can i do anything by calling a javascript function for example? All help appreciated!

Comment: To clarify, i know how to find the actual image URLs, and everything else needed for normal web scraping, i can scrape most simple sites now, i just cant find a source that gives all the tumblr posts from a blog. I can also parse and search in xml.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat, how do you go about tracking the browser calls? Chrome logs? The browser console? Network Packets?

Comment: You would load the new files over AJAX based on the scroll position of the window / body. When the user reaches the end of the page, you make the AJAX call for more information.

Comment: @magreenberg Can AJAX requests be sent with the requests library, or do i need to use something like selenium with the chrome webdriver or the firefox geckodriver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Link Post on Tumblr's API](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#user-methods) or the Python module [PyTumblr](https://github.com/tumblr/pytumblr). But you can't bypass the API Rate Limit using normal methods.

#### Other Rescources

- https://github.com/tumblr/pytumblr
- https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#user-methods
- [How to access Tumblr API Photo Data Feed (i.e. all photos, entire archive)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38567851/how-to-access-tumblr-api-photo-data-feed-i-e-all-photos-entire-archive?rq=1)

Comment: OK, this didn't fix my problem, but you say you can't, so i'll mark it as accepted. I think i found another way by finding that many blogs have a way of getting their post paged, not scrolled. Then i can do some normal scraping. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Your welcome, but what's your way of fixing your problem?

Comment: I used the

 "http://BLOG.tumblr.com/page/" + str(PageNumber)

That gives some number(can't remember, maybe 10) posts and I just increment the page number, scraping images with certain attributes. Couldn't find a  standard attribute for every blog, so I have a list of xpaths to choose between.